# Can I replace a 40A water heater breaker with a 60A breaker to prevent trips?

Tags: hot-water

Double 40 amp breaker tripped as HD want work. Can I use a double 60 amp on my water heater?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "as HD want work"?

Comment: Breaker must be matched with wire size/ampacity  a 40 amp circuit would typically have #8 wire while a 60 amp circuit would require #6 wire

Answer (score 5):

TLDR:  there aren't that many things that handle electricity in a water heater - a couple of switches (unlikely to be them) and a big heating element. None of these parts are expensive.  Why not just fix the heater?  *I don't know how to fix a heater but I know how to change a breaker* - that's an effect my father referred to as "rearranging deck chairs on the *Titanic*". And the cure is "school up".

### Never up-size breakers!

I don't understand how humans develop the logic "Breaker size X trips, let's just use breaker size X+10 or 20 and maybe it won't trip anymore". I guess it's because they don't know *why* breaker sizes are chosen in the first place.

Breakers protect wires and appliances.  Without a correctly sized breaker,  the wire can overheat and start a fire.  Worse, it'll start it inside the walls, where it's impossible to put out a fire early - it will fully engage, there's nothing  you can do about it, and the house is done.

Or the equipment can have an internal fault *that isn't detected by the breaker*.  Of course appliances are safety tested; that's what Underwriter's Laboratories does, and they apply UL listings.  But a UL listing is only good if you install the appliance properly, and that includes the correct breaker size - UL can't vouch for a 30A appliance on a 60A breaker!

---

Obviously, the "up-size the breaker" mentality has already visited your house.  Almost all water heater circuits are 30A, and here you are already at 40A.  I suspect you've already had trip problems, you or the "last guy" has already up-sized the breaker, and *that didn't work* so here you are.  That is because **the underlying problem is still there**.  Your 60 will also trip, and you'll find yourself installing an 80, 100, 150, where does this end?   Why not just forget the breaker and go with this sub-feed lug kit?

[image]

See? It contains no breaker at all, just lugs.  Put a **known-defective** large appliance on *no circuit protection whatsoever* - ***what could possibly go wrong?***

Well, a 60A breaker on a 30A large device and 30A wire is pretty much "no circuit protection whatsoever".

### Or is this a GFCI problem?

You may have a water heater which isn't burning down the wires, just has a ground fault and is tripping a GFCI breaker.   GFCIs aren't required on water heaters, so you could hypothetically replace the GFCI with a plain breaker of the correct size (30A).  *Boy, I hope your supply pipe is metal*... **However, again this does nothing to fix the underlying problem**.

If it's a GFCI trip, the underlying problem is probably dirt/dust in the water heater wiring, or a faulty heating element.

Answer (score 3):

No,
It has tripped for a reason - you need to find the reason :

Faulty heater element,

Earth or ground fault etc

Supply cable to heater fault

Even possibly faulty breaker

But just fitting a bigger breaker is not the solution.